# Encryption not working properly

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

i have this piece of code for encryption.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key) 
token = f.encrypt(b"something cool")
k = f.decrypt(token)
print(k) `
```

This is the output

```
b'something cool'
```

According to the example on the website, that "b" should've gone. I'm very new at this and would like to know or understand how exactly the solution works.

Thanks

Comment: It's a bytes object, it looks correct to me.

Comment: @JamesKPolk seems so for me as well. This is just like the example i saw on the website. But the "b" is still there in the decrypted text in mine

Comment: @PatrickArtner thats my typing mistake

Comment: I have edited and updated my question. I apologize for the typing mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ‘b’ means bytes. So instead of working with strings encryption algorythms are actually using bytes. My experience is that what you give a library (str/bytes/array) it should give you back, which Fernet is doing. I would simply convert the bytes back to a string `k.decode(“utf-8”)`

Comment: Sorry this answer is correct to convert the bytes https://stackoverflow.com/a/606199

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

The encryption functions are doing what they should: bytes in and bytes out.

Cryptography and encryption work with bytes, not strings or other encoding, `decrypt` returns bytes. The actual low level decrypt has no idea of encodings, it can't the decryption could be a string, it could be an image, etc.

It is up to the caller to provide encodings in and out that are appropriate to the data being encrypted/decrypted.

As the caller wrap the encryption in a function you write that provides the correct encodings, in this case a string to bytes on encryption and bytes back to a string on decryption.